# MSSQL linux in AKS - licensing

Tags: azure, azure-aks

How does licensing work in AKS if I host MSSQL there in containers. In the pricing calculator of Azure I don't see any details for this, is there any hidden charges for this if we create containers

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the licensing is similar to that of virtual machines - you either have to license the containers themselves or the physical servers hosting the containers with Enterprise Edition - which would be your AKS nodes in this case.

For some more information you can check out the SQL 2019 licensing data

https://download.microsoft.com/download/f/0/d/f0d7004e-9e39-4991-853b-2aa09e4ce456/SQL%20Server%202019%20%20Licensing%20Datasheet.pdf

Also be mindful of the fact that if you want license containers individually that you might want to check with MS licensing directly whether something like a static CPU policy will satisfy the requirements for CPU pinning.

Comment: but in aks, we dont need to purchase license right? will there be any difference if i spin up a big container in aks? i still dont get it

Comment: In AKS you would still need to purchase a license. AKS only includes the management of the Kubernetes control-plan and you play separately for the compute nodes ( virtual machines) and any software running on those nodes or in container.

To give an example - if you would run JBoss or another commercial product in a container you would still have to license it as well.

With regards to if you use a big or small container - in kubernetes you can set limits and requests but the container will still all the cores of the node. A CPU policy might limit that - but I would still check with MS

Comment: i dont get you, do you have any URL that has details about this

Comment: But of course: https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/5-FAQs-on-SQL-Server-containers-and-how-to-manage-them -> third question